# JS/Vue: Confirming a class is part of a public API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, components

I am using a library for tags in my Vue app and I need to change the tabindex and add an eventListener but I don't have the template accessible to add a custom eventListener to since it's an imported component from a library ( https://github.com/JohMun/vue-tags-input/blob/master/vue-tags-input/vue-tags-input.vue ) .   My workaround is grabbing the element by class `ti-new-tag-input` with vanilla JS and then just setting the `tabIndex` to that. How can I confirm that `ti-new-tag-input` is part of the public API for that library so I can ensure it won't change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set `tabindex` directly on the `vue-tags-input` component.
In the source code you can see, that `$attrs` is bound to the input element, which means, that the `tabindex` should get bound to the element you described too.

https://github.com/JohMun/vue-tags-input/blob/master/vue-tags-input/vue-tags-input.vue#L124

```
<vue-tags-input
  v-model="xxx"
  tabindex="1"
/>
```

Comment: hey @tho-masn, thanks!  I just updated my question because I realized I am not only changing the tabindex but also adding an eventListener on it so that I can do some custom calls when certain keys are pressed.  That is why I am grabbing the class but I just want to make sure the class is part of the public API

Comment: Oh, I see. For the event listeners you could use refs, like `$refs.refNameOfYourVueTagsInputComponent.$refs.newTagInput`. It's not a public API neither, but it's less likely a ref gets changed, than the css class gets changed.

Comment: thanks! I was thinking about this approach but didn't know if it was bad practice to access nested refs like that?

Comment: Actually it is bad practice. But relying on css classes of nested components is even worse, so it's probably the most stable solution you can get.